# use `rhc` client to run local script on remote server

Tags: ssh, openshift-online-2

I was looking at this thread

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine

I am trying to figure out how to use the rhc command to run a local script on the remote server.

I can ssh into my redhat/openshift servers like so:

```
rhc ssh <app-id>
```

Right now, I am copying local scripts from my local machine to the remote using scp.

Does anybody know if there is an `rhc` command to run a local script on that remote server?

or should I just use the `ssh` command instead of `rhc`?

Comment: What is wrong with any of the existing ways to do this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton what is wrong with any of the existing ways to do this? Well, what are the existing ways? I have no idea. If you would please enumerate a few in an answer, I can guarantee some an upvote.

Comment: There are several possibilities in https://serverfault.com/q/617116/126632 and perhaps in other questions as well.

Comment: My upvotes carry special weight, when I click the up arrow, the recipient gets 300 points, not the standard 10. I don't know how long this will last so you should act fast lol.